# How To save users feed data in database in my custom form in WordPress?

Tags: database, wordpress, email

I have created a custom form in my project and also create mail functionality for it. Now i want to save all the data post by users in database how do i achieve it?

Here is my Form:

```
<form id="formMy">
        <input  name="txtFirstName"  type="text" required  placeholder="Name" id="txtFirstName">
            <input  name="PopupContact_email"  type="email"  required  placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="requestemail">
            <input  name="txtOrganisationName"  type="text" required  placeholder="Company/ Institute Name" id="requestcompany">
             <input type="hidden" name="hiddenform">
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg bbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="display:none;">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-inverse"  style="vertical-align:top;" name="submit" onClick="ajaxFormSubmit2();">Request a Demo</button>
    </form>
```

And this is my ajax code:

```
<script>
function ajaxFormSubmit2(){
    var txtFirstName = jQuery('#txtFirstName').val();
    var requestemail = jQuery('#requestemail').val();
    var requestcompany = jQuery('#requestcompany').val();
    var atpos=requestemail.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=requestemail.lastIndexOf(".");

    if(txtFirstName=="" || requestemail=="" || requestcompany==""){
          jQuery('.alertred').show();
          jQuery(".alertred").delay(10000).hide(0);
          jQuery('.alertred').html('<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp;Please Fill out all the fields.');
          return false;
    }
    else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=requestemail.length)
    {
       jQuery('.alertred').show();
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
    jQuery.post("<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/mail2.php'; ?>",{txtFirstName:txtFirstName,requestemail:requestemail,requestcompany:requestcompany},function(r){
        if(r=="success"){
        jQuery('.success').show();

        }
    });

    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the form data using **formId_specifier.serialize()** method. And you get this in your php file like this one example for you.

JS Code::

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#form_id',function(){
  $.post(
        MyAjax.ajax_url,{
            action: AJAX_FILE_URL,
            data: me.serialize()
        }, function(response){
           // Handle after getting response
        }
    );
});
```

In php code you can get form date using this code:

```
parsestr($_POST['data'], $form_data);   // now all form data is assign to $form_data
```

Comment: dear i want to save the data in the database. This code does not seems to be solution to my problem.

Comment: I think you have DB Connection into your **AJAX_FILE_URL** file, right ? So if you want to save one by one data into database use a **foreach** loop otherwise if you want to save all data into one cell please make the array a json sting using **JSON_ENCODE** method and after that you can store. Am I right?